# JSON - Angular - ¿Como macheo este JSON en mi modelo?

Tags: json, typescript, angular

tengo dudas de como consumir JSON en Angular, ya que no puedo machear bien los datos del JSON en mi modelo.

Ejemplo de JSON: http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=coldplay

Mi modelo es el siguiente

```
export class Artist {
  idArtist: string;
  strArtist: string;
  strStyle: string;
  strWebsite: string;
  strBiographyES: string;
  strArtistLogo: string;
  strArtistBanner: string;
}
```

Mi Observable:

```
getArtist(): void {
    this.musicService.getArtist()
    .subscribe(artists => this.artist = artists );
  }
```

Mi metodo para consumo de la API:

```
 getArtist(): Observable<Artist[]> {
    const URL = 'http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/1/search.php?s=coldplay';
    return this.httpClient.get<Artist[]>(URL).pipe(
      tap( _ => console.log(`artist found`)),
      catchError( this.handleError('getArtist', []))
    );
  }
```

Si hago un print de mi objeto del tipo Artist en TypeScript consigo EXACTAMENTE lo mismo que en el ejemplo JSON anteriormente ejemplificado. 
¿A que se debe que no machea? ¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

El modelo se puede modificar si es necesario, no tengo restricciones de ningun tipo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que obtienes y qué haces para reproducir el mismo comportamiento?

Comment: No da error, por consola devuelve 'artist found'.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta: ¿Qué significa que *no machea*?